# How to check the software installed folder and do the silent update in same path in NSIS

Tags: c#, wpf, nsis

We have .Net WPF application which will be updating itself when update is available using NSIS. But right now NSIS installing the software in ProgramFiles directly even if the software already installed in some other path.
How to make it to install in the same path where previous version was installed.

```
    ; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

; http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsProcess_plugin is needed now for killing the client process!

RequestExecutionLevel admin
!define MULTIUSER_EXECUTIONLEVEL Admin
;!define MULTIUSER_NOUNINSTALL ;Uncomment if no uninstaller is created
!include MultiUser.nsh

!ifndef BUILD_TARGET
    !define BUILD_TARGET "Release"
!endif

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!ifndef PRODUCT_VERSION
  !define PRODUCT_VERSION "0.0.0.0"
!endif

!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "MYcompany"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyApp.exe"
!define RUN_REG_KEY "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"
;BUILD_DIR has to be in relation to the .nsi file

!define BUILD_DIR "..\..\Bin\${BUILD_TARGET}"

!if ${BUILD_TARGET} == "Debug"
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp  2.0 Debug"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "https://127.0.0.1:3000/"
!define MUI_ICON "..\MyApp\Resources\Icons\IconRed.ico"
!endif

!if ${BUILD_TARGET} == "ReleaseTest"
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp  2.0 Staging"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "www.ggle.com"
!define MUI_ICON "..\MyApp\Resources\Icons\IconBlue.ico"
!endif

!if ${BUILD_TARGET} == "Release"
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp  2.0"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "www.gole.com"
!define MUI_ICON "..\MyApp\Resources\Icons\IconBlack.ico"
!endif


!include "MUI2.nsh"

; 64 bit support
!include x64.nsh

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING

!define MUI_UNICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-uninstall.ico"
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "..\MyApp\Resources\Icons\installer.bmp"
!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "..\MyApp\Resources\Icons\installer.bmp"

; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
;Custom page
Page custom DirectoryLeave 
; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page
; Use the SHOWREADME for creating Desktop shortcut
;Function createDesktopShortcut
 ; CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" "-shortcut"
;FunctionEnd

Function DirectoryLeave
  MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "MY App requires a large amount of space for storing builds. Please install MyApp Mate on a drive that has a large amount of space free."  IDOK yes 
  yes: Abort
FunctionEnd

;!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME ""
;!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_NOTCHECKED
;!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_TEXT "Create Desktop Shortcut"
;!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_FUNCTION createDesktopShortcut

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Uninstaller pages
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW un.ModifyUnWelcome
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE un.LeaveUnWelcome
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; MUI end ------
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
OutFile "MyAppSetup.exe"
VIProductVersion ${PRODUCT_VERSION}

VIAddVersionKey ProductName "${PRODUCT_NAME} Installer"
VIAddVersionKey CompanyName "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
VIAddVersionKey LegalCopyright "MyCompany 2018"
VIAddVersionKey FileDescription "Installs ${PRODUCT_NAME}"
VIAddVersionKey FileVersion ${PRODUCT_VERSION}
VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion ${PRODUCT_VERSION}
VIAddVersionKey OriginalFilename "MyAppSetup.exe"

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
ShowInstDetails show
ShowUnInstDetails show

Function .onInit
  !insertmacro MULTIUSER_INIT
  ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "QuietUninstallString"
  StrCmp $R0 "" done uninst


  ;Run the uninstaller
  uninst:
  ClearErrors
  Exec '$R0' ; instead of the ExecWait line

  done:
  ${If} ${RunningX64}
    ; disable registry redirection (enable access to 64-bit portion of registry)
    SetRegView 64
    ; change install dir 
    StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  ${Else}
    MessageBox MB_OK "${PRODUCT_NAME} needs 64bit Windows!"
    Abort
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onInstSuccess
  RMDir /r "$LOCALAPPDATA\${PRODUCT_NAME}"

  IfSilent startlauncher finished
  startlauncher:
    Exec '"$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"'
  finished:
FunctionEnd

Section "MainSection" SEC01
  Call EnsureNotRunning



  Delete "$INSTDIR\INIFileParser.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\log4net.config"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\log4net.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\log4net.xml"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Newtonsoft.Json.xml"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.Core.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.Core.dll.config"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe.config"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\SocketIoClientDotNet.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\WebSocket4Net.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Show log files.lnk"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk"


  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite on
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\EngineIoClientDotNet.dll"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\INIFileParser.dll"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\log4net.config"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\log4net.dll"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\log4net.xml"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\Newtonsoft.Json.xml"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\MyApp.Core.dll"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\MyApp.Core.dll.config"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\MyApp.exe"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\MyApp.exe.config"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\SocketIoClientDotNet.dll"
  File "${BUILD_DIR}\WebSocket4Net.dll"

  SetOverwrite on
  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" "-shortcut"
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe" "-shortcut"

  CreateShortCut "$INSTDIR\Show log files.lnk" "$WINDIR\explorer.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MyApp" "$WINDIR\system32\imageres.dll" 172
SectionEnd

Section -AdditionalIcons
  WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.URL" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe$\""
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "QuietUninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe$\" /S"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"

    ; estimated size
  ${GetSize} "$INSTDIR" "/S=0K" $0 $1 $2
  IntFmt $0 "0x%08X" $0
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "EstimatedSize" "$0"

  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "VersionMajor" 2
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "VersionMinor" 0



  ; Runs on Windows start-up
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${RUN_REG_KEY}" "MyApp" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
SectionEnd


!macro NOTRUNNINGMACRO un
Function ${un}EnsureNotRunning
  ${DisableX64FSRedirection}
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  nsExec::ExecToStack 'Powershell.exe -inputformat none -noprofile "(get-process -name MyApp).Kill()"'

  nsExec::ExecToStack 'Powershell.exe -inputformat none -noprofile "net share ayapp /delete"'

  ${EnableX64FSRedirection}

  Sleep 500
  performCheck:
  System::Call 'kernel32::OpenMutex(i 0x100000, b 0, t "Global\{${BUILD_TARGET} }") i .R0'
  IntCmp $R0 0 backupCheck isRunning isRunning
  backupCheck:
  System::Call 'kernel32::OpenMutex(i 0x100000, b 0, t "Global\{0}") i .R0'
  IntCmp $R0 0 notRunning isRunning isRunning
  isRunning:
  System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(i $R0)'
  MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "${PRODUCT_NAME} is running. Please close it first" /SD IDCANCEL IDOK performCheck
  Abort
  notRunning:
FunctionEnd
!macroend

!insertmacro NOTRUNNINGMACRO ""
!insertmacro NOTRUNNINGMACRO "un."

Function un.onUninstSuccess
  HideWindow
  IfSilent finished
    MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "${PRODUCT_NAME} was successfully removed from your computer."
  finished:
FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
  !insertmacro MULTIUSER_UNINIT
FunctionEnd

Var keepUserSettingsCheckbox
Var keepUserSettingsBool

Function un.ModifyUnWelcome
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 120u -18u 50% 12u "Remove user settings"
Pop $keepUserSettingsCheckbox
SetCtlColors $keepUserSettingsCheckbox "" ${MUI_BGCOLOR}
${NSD_Check} $keepUserSettingsCheckbox ; Check it by default
FunctionEnd

Function un.LeaveUnWelcome
${NSD_GetState} $keepUserSettingsCheckbox $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    StrCpy $keepUserSettingsBool "True"
${Else}
    StrCpy $keepUserSettingsBool "False"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function un.GetMyDocs
  ReadRegStr $0 HKCU \
             "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" \
             Personal
FunctionEnd

Section Uninstall
  Call un.EnsureNotRunning

  Delete "$INSTDIR\INIFileParser.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\log4net.config"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\log4net.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\log4net.xml"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Newtonsoft.Json.xml"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.Core.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.Core.dll.config"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe.config"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\SocketIoClientDotNet.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\WebSocket4Net.dll"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Show log files.lnk"


  Delete "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\*.*"
  RMDir /r "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}"

  StrCmp $keepUserSettingsBool "True" 0 +11
  Delete "$LOCALAPPDATA\${PRODUCT_NAME}\*.*"
  RMDir /r "$LOCALAPPDATA\${PRODUCT_NAME}"

  Call un.GetMyDocs
  RMDir /r "$0\${PRODUCT_NAME}"

  Delete "$DESKTOP\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk"

  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
  DeleteRegValue HKLM "Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Posting code without relevant includes and defines is not very helpful!

Comment: @Anders Edited the code, can you please check it now,

Answer (score 1):

`InstallDirRegKey` will read from the specified registry value and initialize `$InstDir` with the read path (overriding the `InstallDir` attribute) before `.onInit` is called but you have to write this registry value yourself in one of your `Section`s.

You have not posted all your code so it is hard to say what is really going on but you seem to be using MultiUser for some reason and it has its own defines you need to set: `MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR`, `MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_KEY` and `MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_VALUENAME`.

```
Section
!ifdef MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_KEY & MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_VALUENAME
  ${If} $MultiUser.InstallMode == CurrentUser
    WriteRegStr HKCU "${MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_KEY}" "${MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_VALUENAME}" "$InstDir"
  ${Else}
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_KEY}" "${MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_REGISTRY_VALUENAME}" "$InstDir"
  ${EndIf}
!else
  WriteRegStr HK?? Software\?? ?? "$InstDir" ; Must match key used in InstallDirRegKey
!endif
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I have updated my code, Can you please check it now and let me know how to proceed.

Comment: You are not writing the registry value in your section

Comment: I am not aware of this NSIS scripts acutally, I am working on ASP.NET MVC and as part of my time they have this WPF application, Basically this was written by someone else so am not sure what is happening in this script so could you please help me where and how can i write the things. Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need a `WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" $InstDir` instruction in one of your sections. When you use MultiUser.nsh you are supposed to use its defines but I don't know how to explain that any further than I already have.

Comment: I have added as you said but its installing the the Programfiles\MyApp path only instead of E://MyApp path.

Comment: Are you defining the `MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_INSTDIR_*` values?